# SELECT MAX(id) in an empty table returns NULL instead of 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

I need to remedy a problem about invalid auto-increment on failed inserts, in case some unique fields were duplicated.

**Database**

```
   id : primary key(11) NOT NULL  // !important: doesn't have auto increment
field : varchar(25) NOT NULL
```

**Query**

```
$field = 'field1';
try{
    $conn = new PDO("....");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id,field) VALUES (((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table as table_max_id)+1),:field)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':field', $field, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if(!$stmt->execute())
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());//Column id cannot be null;
 }
 ...
```

The error found is:

> Column id can not be null;

This verification error only if the table is empty does not occur if there is a record in the table.

I could solve the problem by putting a field with a fake `id = 1`, but I do not really like it as a solution, any ideas?

Comment: Why wouldn't id be an auto increment?

Comment: @Devon 
Because the table contains unique fields that can be duplicated by mistake, and if it happens the database does not insert any new records but increases the id the same: the result is that there are missing ids, for example 1,2,3, 4.6, the index 5 would be lost forever.

Comment: The only thing I can think of with missing IDs is if you rollback a transaction, but this is on purpose because you wouldn't want another connection trying to use the same ID if your transaction is committed.   If you delete a row, unless it's equal to the MAX(id), you'd still have missing indexes...

Comment: A design that relies on ids being contiguous does not look right.

Comment: If a single field is duplicated (I do not speak of the id) it is not inserted, but the id in the database is increased by 1, this is a big problem I have to solve, that's why the operation.

Comment: @Salman The real problem was the leap of many unassigned 'id' fields. How do you solve the problem, do you say that it is the same if they are not generated in sequence?

Comment: @Devon No row is ever deleted in the database, under any circumstances: if it were possible to eliminate them I would not have posed this problem.

Comment: @User if no row is deleted and no transactions are rolled back, you should never have gaps in your ids using auto-increment...

Comment: @User MySQL INNODB engine does not guarantee contiguous autoincrement values and `INSERT IGNORE` might increment the counter without inserting. What I said above is that ideally the database design should not have any issues with gaps. But I understand that it is a special requirement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to replace NULL expression with something else:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1 FROM table
```

I would suggest using an `AUTO_NUMBER` field instead of generating the id.